# pywinauto not seeing elements visible via inspect.exe

Tags: python, ui-automation, pywinauto

I am automating a third party application with pywinauto. I am able to see some specific elements and their texts when using e.g. inpect.exe, but when looking at pywinauto's print_control_identifiers these elements are not included at all (marked with red in the image between the two green ones).

[print_control_identifiers VS Inspect.exe (red ones are missing)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToUWT.png)

Is it somehow possible to see these elements with pywinauto?

In this particular case I need to check for example if an element containing the text "Varoitus!" exists, but for some reason pywinauto can't see it at all.

Comment: Did you try both backends?  (uia and win32)

Comment: "uia" backend is definitely used, from this point of view it's OK. But sometimes pywinauto output and `Inspect.exe` tree are a little bit different. I guess it's because we use `FindAll` method from UI Automation API for performance reasons while `Inspect.exe` uses `RawViewWalker` object. We implemented this option in `atspi` branch of pywinauto but it will be released significantly later and it contains some other serious improvements that partially break backward compatibility.

Comment: OK, thanks for the answer @VasilyRyabov! I will figure out some workaround for my use case.